# How to Pass multiple Object in UseHistory in react router dom?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-router

Please help how to pass multiple objects in useHistory in React?
I know how to pass one state,

```
onClick={()=>useHistory.push("/child", {gender})}
```

where gender is an array as:

```
const gender=[
{ id: 'male', title: 'Male' },
{ id: 'female', title: 'Female' },
{ id: 'other', title: 'Other' },]
```

how to pass another array like gender together / simultaneously.
please help.

Answer (score 0):

The second parameter of the `push` function does not limit you to a single element. You are currently passing an object containing the key `gender` with the value of your genrer array (as `{gender}` is equivalent to `{gender: gender}`.

So you can pass additional properties as follow:

```
let history = useHistory();
...
history.push({gender, otherVariable, someOtherVariable});
```